# How can I find the maximum print size in centimeters based on width and height of a jpeg?

Tags: linear-algebra

I think that this is super simple but I'm not good with math.

So I have a bunch of 'big' images (3000px x 3000px) and I want to print them with the maximum size in centimeters without losing quality, I've been researching and I'm using python to make some calculations

> There are 2.54 centimeters per inch; if it is sufficient to assume 96
> pixels per inch, the formula is rather simple:
>
> centimeters = pixels * 2.54 / 96

So i'm doing something like
width * 2.54 / 150 dpi

But now I'm reading about PPI and I don't know how to make the equation

> What is PPI? The first step to understanding how to print high-quality photos is to understand pixels per inch (PPI). The pixels on your digital camera or computer screen get converted into dots on the printed photo. The more pixels you have per inch (centimeter), the sharper your photos will be. A general rule of thumb is to try to have a PPI of between 200 and 400
>
> Calculating PPI The basic equation for calculating PPI is: PPI = width(pixels)/ width of image (inches); PPI = height(pixels)/ height of image (inches). So, for example, if you want to print a 4-inch-by-6-inch image, and your pixel count is 800 x 1200, you need to divide 800 (the pixel height) by 4 (the photo height) and then divide 1200 (the pixel width) by 6 (the photo width). The PPI will be 200, providing you with good quality photos. However, if you want to print a larger photo, for example 8-inch-by-10-inch photo, the PPI reduces to 100 for width and 120 for height, giving you lower quality prints.

But how can I get the biggest print size of an image with a 200 PPI?

Comment: The formula you did “something like” is fine for 150 PPI. To get 200 PPI, use 200 instead of 150.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have 3000 pixels and print at 200 pixels per inch, you have
$$  \frac{3000 \,\text{pixels}}{200 \,\frac{\text{pixels}}{\text{inch}}} = 15 \,\text{inches}  $$
of image.

Two ways to get centimeters:

- From inches: 
  $$  15 \,\text{inches} \cdot \frac{2.54 \,\text{cm}}{1 \,\text{inch}} = 38.1 \,\text{cm}  \text{.}  $$
- Altering the units in the formula:
  $$  \frac{3000 \,\text{pixels}}{200 \,\frac{\text{pixels}}{\text{inch}} \cdot \frac{1 \,\text{inch}}{2.54 \,\text{cm}}} = 38.1 \,\text{cm}  $$

Comment: thank you, so simple

Comment: @ribas : No worries.  I also wrestle with unfamiliar units at times.

Comment: so if I need this in centimeters I would do something like width / 200 * 2.54?

Comment: @ribas : Updated answer with two options for arriving at centimeters.